# Shiny downloadHandler not working

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny downloadHandler

in **server.R**:

```
  output$DownloadButton <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("test", Sys.Date(), ".csv",sep="")
    },
    content = function(con) {
      print("in download")

print(con) # this prints C:\\Users\\me\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpI1EjY7\\file668338e4c33
  Data<-ReactiveGetData()$Data #Here I get the data I want to download
  print(head(Data)) #This prints out the data with no errors
  write.csv(Data, con)
}
  )
```

here is **ui.r:**

```
  sidebarPanel(
    downloadButton("DownloadButton", label = "Download",class = NULL), ....
```

So far it printed the temp file:

```
C:\\Users\\me\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpI1EjY7\\file668338e4c33
```

**BUT When I go to this path manually I get an error saying "File not found"**

and then when I click on the download button I do not get an error and nothing happens.

Any idea why the temp file doesn't seem to be created?

Should the temp file end in csv?

**HERE IS AN EVER SIMPLER EXAMPLE which you can run if you run the server.r and ui.r files belwo. I cannot download the file below:**

**The "file" object does not exist below any idea why?**

**ui.r**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    downloadButton("Download", label = "Download",class = NULL)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("test",
               h3("test")
      )
    )
  )
))
```

**server.r**

```
library(rJava)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


  output$Download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("test.csv",sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      print("in download")
      print(file) #this file does not exist ???
      Data<- data.frame(name= c(1,2,3,4))
      print(head(Data))
      write.csv(Data, file)
    }
  )

})#end of server function
```

you can run this by:

```
library(rJava)
library(shiny)
runApp("C://Users//me//pathToShinyProjectFolder")
```

SOULTION:  click "open in browser" in upper left and user CHROME OR FIREFOX as default browser.

Comment: Is `Data` a reactive object? should it be `Data()` instead?

Comment: John - The ReactiveData() is reactive and the $Data is member of a list that is returned so no it does not need to be ReactiveData()$Data()

Comment: I agree with @JohnPaul, you should make the data an object like `outData <- reactive({...})` and then call it like so: `write.csv(outData(), file = con)`

Comment: mkemp - the issue is not with the data because I can print it out "print(head(Data))".  I can see the data in the "Data" object.

Comment: Good point... just wondering, any specific reason to have double \?

Comment: Mkemp/John -- Can you run the server.r and ui.r at the bottom of the question. That simple example does not work for me.

Comment: Works fine with shiny 0.10.2.2

Comment: Are you trying to have shiny save the data to a particular place or allow the user just download the data?  If the latter, did you try clicking 'open in browser'?  Your code seems to work fine.  If the former, you should define the path more explicitly.  That directory printed above is by definition temporary, nothing you want to keep should ever be saved there.

Comment: cdeterman - I am trying to allow the user to click the "Download" button and save the .csv file somewhere. What are you referring to when you say open in browser?  Shouldn't this work when the user presses "Download"?

Comment: @John Paul -- does the temp file exist on your computer at the temp file path populated with 1,2,3,4?

Comment: @user3022875, I assume you are using Rstudio as your IDE?  If so, you run your app and it opens another window with your shiny application.  In the top left there is a button "Open in Browser".  Click it and it will open in your default browser.  In the browser, you can click download and it works fine for me.

Comment: @user3022875 Yes - I was able to chose a download location though, rather than have it assinged.

Comment: @cdeterman when I do that I get an error "ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer"  any thoughts?

Comment: @user3022875, something appears strange then.  What version of shiny are you using?  Are you using the exact code you provided above (the simple example)?  Make sure you don't close the original shiny window.  I ran the exact code for the 'simple' example and it works fine when it opens in my firefox browser.

Comment: @cdeterman -- I think it is because I am using IE. Do you know how to change my browser to make it Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: @user3022875, you would need to change your default browser.  Otherwise, you could just paste localhost:port in the browser of your choosing.  'port' is the 4 digit number after the colon at the top of your shiny app window.

Comment: @cdeterman - It was definetly the browser. It working in Chrome.

Comment: @user3022875, good, I will post as the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try opening the application in another browser.  Not all browsers are created equally.  This can be done by simply typing the following in another browser of your choosing.

```
localhost:5586
```

Note, that the port number may be different for you.

Comment: Yes, same problem for me. It seems that when you run the app in mode "window" instead of "external" (browser) the download fails.